# jQuery Datatables json AJAX help pls "No Data Available in Table"

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a table that is made in the `$( document ).ready`function. I am also using the jQuery DataTables plugin. For some reason, when the page loads, the table loads but the first row says:

> "No Data Available in Table".

This my controller:

```
  public string Lowx()
        {
            var query = db.Infoes.
                Include(x => x.Profile).
                Include(x => x.Car).

                ToList();

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToList());
```

This my Ajax function:

```
 $(document).ready(function (data) {

          $('#cars').DataTable({


              ajax: {
                  url: '@Url.Action("lowx")',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  dataSrc: ""

              },
              columns: [
                  { data: "FirstName", name: "FirstName" },
                  { data: "LastName", name: "LastName" },
                  { data: "MiddleName", name: "MiddleName" },
                  { data: "BirthDate", name: "BirthDate" },
                  { data: "CarName", name: "CarName" },
                  { data: "CarNumber", name: "CarNumber" },

              ],




    });
});
```

Datatables write:

[image]

Comment: Default http verb is GET but Ajax is sending POST, have you tried adding `[HttpPost]` decorator? Can you see any error in console?

Comment: @derloopkat 0 error in console

Comment: this might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html.  It's expecting an object with an array property called "data" that contains the data, not a straight array.

Also,

(a) Your controller action is returning a string.  You should return a `JsonResult` which does the serialization for you (and sets mime types etc appropriately).

```
public JsonResult Lowx()
{
    var query = db.Infoes.
        Include(x => x.Profile).
        Include(x => x.Car).
        ToList();

    return Json(new { data = query });
}
```

Ideally, you should just get the data you need instead of retrieving all the columns in the table(s).  This is making a complete guess as to what your schema looks like, but...

```
public JsonResult Lowx()
{
    var query = db.Infoes.
        Select(x => new()
        {
            FirstName = x.Profile.FirstName,
            LastName = x.Profile.LastName,
            MiddleName = x.Profile.MiddleName,
            BirthDate = x.Profile.BirthDate,
            CarName = x.Car.CarName,
            CarNumber = x.Car.CarNumber
        });

    return Json(new { data = query });
}
```

(b) Why are you using a POST request to retrieve data?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

javascript:

```
  $('#cars').dataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "searching": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    dom: 'Blrtip',
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $('#cars').data('source'),
    "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
     "columns": [
                  { data: "FirstName"},
                  { data: "LastName"},
                  { data: "MiddleName"},
                  { data: "BirthDate"},
                  { data: "CarName",
                  { data: "CarNumber"},

              ], 
  });
```

html code:

```
<table id="cars" data-source="lowx">
          <thead>
            <tr role="row">
              <th>first name</th>
              .....
              <th>car number</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody> 
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

visit this url for more info: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()

```
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: "data.json"
    } );

    table.ajax.url( 'newData.json' ).load();
```